# Makefile: dynamic dependency order

Tags: makefile

I have the following scenario:

```
all: file4.txt

file1.txt:
    ./program parameter1

file2.txt: file1.txt
    ./program parameter2

file3.txt: file2.txt
    ./program parameter3

file4.txt: file3.txt
    ./program parameter4
```

So, `./program parameter1` creates file1.txt, `./program parameter2` creates file2.txt, etc. And file3.txt can only be created if file2.txt already exists and file2.txt can only be created when file1.txt exists. But sometimes `./program parameters2` is able to create both file2.txt AND file3.txt. So there is no need to run the file3.txt target anymore but instead file4.txt should be created directly. In fact, rerunning the file3.txt target would break file3.txt in this case.

Is there a way to re-evaluate dependencies or somehow skip over target file3.txt if this file has been created? If I run `make file2.txt` and then `make file4.txt` this works and the target file3.txt is never executed. But running `make file4.txt` from the beginning will trigger the file3.txt target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest question is "how do you know if file3.txt needs to be updated or not?"  If the only way is if the param2 run does *NOT* write it, then you'll have trouble if an old version is lying around.  So about the only way to do it safely is to explicitly remove the old one and check if it is created.  So you end up wanting something like:

```
file2.txt: file1.txt
    rm file3.txt  # make sure not to leave an old version around
    ./program parameter2

file3.txt: file2.txt
    if [ -r $@ ]; then         \
        touch $@;              \
    else                       \
        ./program parameter3;  \
    fi
```